# Excel VBA: Use Checkbox Value When Command Button Entered

Tags: excel, vba, button, checkbox, command

I'm trying to teach myself VBA by programming one of those old 'Choose Your Own Adventure' books in Excel (just for my own fun, not to sell).  I have a sheet with a single ActiveX Checkbox ("chkTakeCoins") and a separate command button.  These are not in a Userform, they're just on the sheet.  I can't figure out how to write the Command Button code to see if chkTakeCoins is true or false.  Do I need to Call the chkTakeCoins checkbox from the command button code?  As it's written below I get an 'Object required' error.

```
    Sub btn5to147_Click()
        If chkTakeCoins.Value = True Then
             Sheets("Inventory").Range("coins") = 1
        Else
             Sheets("Inventory").Range("coins") = 0
        End If
        Worksheets("147").Activate
    End Sub
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: What line is generating the error? If the button and checkbox are on sheet "Inventory" then qualify the objects with the specific sheet name, for example; `If Sheets("Inventory").chkTakeCoins.Value = True Then`. Also, make sure you have a range named "coins" on that sheet